# Initialize standalone databases, Spring Boot and MyBatis

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data, mybatis

I'm building Spring Boot + MyBatis project using standalone postgresql database.

Well, for some reason, "convention-based" database initialization doesn't occur. I added data source manually, created sql-scripts, but when I run the project, from the log it's not even processing these scripts. I want to **understand** how the process works for not-embedded databases.

Can one create an instance of data source using code?

Should I link data source in property file or separate class?

What one should do to link separate data source (postgresql in this case) with Spring Boot configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes

   ```
   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {
       DataSourceBuilder.create()
                        .url("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database")
                        .username("username")
                        .password("password")
                        ...
                        .build();
   }
   ```

   2-3. You can use property file along with providing java based DataSourceConfiguration

   ```
   spring.datasource.url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database
   spring.datasource.username: username
   spring.datasource.password: pasword
   ```

   And refers these properties in your Configuration class as follows:

   ```
   @Bean
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
   public DataSource dataSource() {
       return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
   }
   ```

If you have only one database to connect to, the most convenient way is to add it's connection properties into property file, prefixed with `spring.datasource` ([scroll here to check available options](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)) and add `org.postgresql` dependency to pom.xml (build.grade) file and SpringBoot will do the rest.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm using `application.properties` file, connection to data source established well, but it seems like springboot is not even trying to connect. I mean, the scripts `schema.sql` `data.sql` must be executed before server deployment, and I don't even track it in log files, even using `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`.

Comment: If you set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property to `create-drop` or `create`, than these scripts are omitted. Schema is generated based on your entites and you can place initialization sql into `import.sql` file in the root of the classpath.